# List of currently opened cable cars in Switzerland

Tags: switzerland, hiking, alps

I am looking for a list which contains all currently opened cable cars in Switzerland. Many cable cars in Switzerland, during autumn, are closed, and checking one by one for their availability is a time-consuming process. I tried to google but did not find any interesting results.

Comment: This question seems very broad to me. Can you be a bit more specific? I also think the answer can depend on anti-coronameasures.

Comment: I am not sure how can I be more specific. I will try to give you an example. There is a page: https://www.alpen-paesse.ch which shows current status of all passes (if they are closed, open, etc). I would like to find a similar page which shows current status of cable cars. I know that there is this page: https://geovisualist.com/2015/08/01/a-map-of-all-the-mountains-in-switzerland-accessible-by-public-transport/ which contains some list of cable cars but not all and does not have information about availability.

Comment: Well, I am assuming that you want to go somewhere? Hiking, skiing or whatever. I am saying this because these kind of questions tend to be closed on here.

Comment: You might want to ask whether they have glass-paned windows or open barred windows.  If the former, getting in a cable car with a bunch of other people probably isn't a good idea right now.

Comment: @Kyralessa Masks are mandatory in all cable cars (and trains and a lot of other places) right now.

Comment: I mean, honestly, going to Switzerland at all is not a good idea right now.  Thousands of new Covid-19 cases are being reported there every day.  I live in Germany and work across the border in Switzerland.  This is my third straight week of working from home, because it's not safe to go to Switzerland.  Most of our office is working from home.  I like the Swiss.  I work with a lot of them.  But I wouldn't get into a cable car with a bunch of Swiss right now!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of regional restrictions due to Covid-19:

- https://www.myswitzerland.com/en-ch/planning/transport-accommodation/travel-to-switzerland/where-and-when-is-what-open/

"Mountain Railyways" include transport cable cars (ie. access to a village). "Slopes" would include skiing cable cars (ie. access to slopes/mountain peak, but no village there).

And this is probably most relevant list of open ski resorts (most of them would have some cable cars):

- https://www.skiresort.info/snow-reports/switzerland/filter/open-ski-resorts/

There is no really a list with gondolas specifically, so the two above are the closes to what you are looking for.